# how filter_resource_access loads resource(instance) in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, before-filter

I am using `declarative_authorization` gem in my project.

Awards controllers:

```
filter_resource_access :collection => [:index, :award_winners], :nested_in => :users
```

I have a models `Users and Awards`, `Users has many awards` this is my relationships.

Could any one let me know, how `index` and `award_winners` load the resources.
This is working fine, but now I have to modify `award winners` resource(instance) because somewhere its now reloaded and my resources are coming in wrong order.